# How to navigate through a website and "mine information"

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I want to "simulate" navigation through a website and parse the responses.

I just want to make sure i am doing something reasonable before i start, I saw 2 options to do so:

1. Using the WebBrowser class.
2. Using the HttpWebRequest class.

So my initial though was to use HttpWebRequest and just parse the response.

What do you guys think?

Also wanted to ask,i use c# cause its my strongest language, but what are common languages used to do such stuff as mining from websites?

Answer (score 0):

If you start doing it manually, you probably will end up hard-coding lots of cases. Try [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or something else support xpath expressions.

There are alot of Mining and ETL tools out there for serious data mining needs.

Answer (score 0):

For "user simulation" I would suggest using [Selenum web driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), which is much faster but has some limitations in browser emulation, while Selenium provides almost 100% browser features support.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to mine data from a website there is something you must do first in order to be 'polite' to the websites you are mining from. You have to obey the rules set in that websites robots.txt, which is almost always located at www.example.com/robots.txt.

Then use HTML Agility Pack to traverse the website.

Or Convert the html document to xhtml using html2xhtml. Then use an xml parser to traverse the website.

Remember to:

1. Check for duplicate pages. (general idea is to hash each the html doc at each url. Look up (super)shingles)
2. Respect the robots.txt
3. Get the absolute URL from each page
4. Filter duplicate URL from your queue
5. Keep track of the URLs you have visited(ie. timestamp)
6. Parse your html doc. And keep your queue updated.

Keywords: robots.txt, absolute URL, html parser, URL normalization, mercator scheme.

Have fun.